# Needed to update an existing DAX measure, to work in a specific way

Tags: dax, calculation, measure, group

I have the following table in Power BI

EpiDates  (few thousands records)

```
       Period   ClientID   AdmDate      DischDate       LOS

       1             222   5/23/2022    12/31/2050      396
       2             222   5/23/2022    12/31/2050      396
       3             222   5/23/2022    12/31/2050      396
       2             333   3/01/2022    12/31/2050      479
       3             333   3/01/2022    12/31/2050      479
       0             444   1/23/2023    12/31/2050      151
       1             444   1/23/2023    12/31/2050      151
       2             555   1/23/2023     2/23/2023       30
```

I need to create DAX measure – [Active Clients], which will calculate the unique numbers of clients - [ClientID], for the clients, where [DischDate] = 12/31/2050

I have the following DAX code:

```
 CALCULATE (DISTINCTCOUNT (EpiDates'[ClientID] ), 
            EpiDates'[DischDate]= DATE(2050, 12, 31))
```

But, when I create a Matrix in Power BI, I receive the following:

```
      Period   # Active Clients
      0        1
      1        2
      2        2
      3        2
```

My [Active Clients] measure counts [ClientID]s for each [Period] used as grouped column.

While my goal is to create Matrix, where my measure will count [ClientID]s FOR THE HIGHEST [Period] VALUEs ONLY, for each ClientID, as following:

```
    Period    # Active Clients
    1         1
    3         2
```

Period 1 is the highest for the ClientID = 444 (1 Active Client counted)

Period 3 is the highest for the ClientIDs 333, 222 (2 Active Clients counted)

Period 2 is the highest for the ClientID = 555, but [DischDate] is not 12/31/2050
(not counted)

Period 0 has no ClientIDs for which this Period is the highest
(no ClientIDs counted)

Please HELP – if it’s possible to update my existing measure to work the way described above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a variable, `MaxPeriod`, to store the maximum period value from the `EpiDates` table. Then, you will filter the data based on this maximum period value, along with the condition for the discharge date being December 31, 2050.

```
Active Clients = 
VAR MaxPeriod =
    MAX(EpiDates[Period])  -- Calculate the maximum period
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(EpiDates[ClientID]),
        EpiDates[DischDate] = DATE(2050, 12, 31),
        EpiDates[Period] = MaxPeriod  -- Filter by the maximum period
    )
```